# asp.net MVC automatic sending mail every day (without windows service)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I am searching for the best way to create a automatic mail system which fires every day (e.g. 00:00:00) and sends a list of mails.

Which is the best option to perform this task without slow down my application or harm to the server.

I don't want to use windows service to achieve this task. because i am using a shared windows hosting and they don't allow me to run it on the server

Thank you.

Comment: What about run this functionality in other thread (task)?

Comment: Who is going to fire your event everyday without a service? If you have sql-server, you can use server agent to do it.

Comment: What does MVC has to do with this? The Windows Task Scheduler can probably do this. Just create a small program that will send the emails.

Comment: I assume you don't want a service because you're using a hosting environment and don't have access to install your own service, and likewise with a scheduled task.  You really need to explain why you don't want to use the most obvious route, otherwise people will just argue with you.

Comment: @MystereMan you are right!!

Comment: @pinoy_ISF thanks for guidance. can u give a deetail info about task scheduler used with c#

Comment: @Kaf i have a sql server database, which is used to read the birthdays of the users who born on today (current date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which database do you use ? If its MS Sql Server You can use

THE `sp_send_dbmail`  as a part of a stored procedure to send email.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

You can then set up the stored procedure as a Sql Server Agent job to run at regular intervals as shown below

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/create-and-schedule-a-job-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: +1 yes i am using ms sql server for database operations, thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could put WCF service with Quartz.NET http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/ aboard on the same IIS or on another machine.

This approach also allows you to have API to control your scheduler.

Regrads.